# Is cracking MD5 hash a form of P VS NP problem?

Tags: computational-complexity, cryptography

I have a question,Is cracking MD5 hash a form of P VS NP problem?

Comment: no its not      aaaaaaaa

Comment: Forgetting about md5, I reckon you mean "inverting a one-way function." Not the same type (decision problem), not the same formulation as P vs. NP, and not the same "measure" (average case hardness vs. worst-case). [But there are connections.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because finding a preimage of a MD5 hash (which I assume is what you mean by "cracking" it) is a problem with a fixed, unchangeable input size, namely 128 bits.

P versus NP is about how well the best possible algorithm for a problem *scales* when the size of the input goes towards infinity. A problem with a limited input size does not allow that question to be asked at all.

Knowing that P$\ne$NP would tell us nothing about how fast an algorithm for finding MD5 preimages would be.

Knowing that P$=$NP wouldn't really tell us anything. It would imply that there's a polynomial-time algorithm that takes a description of a hash function (assuming the *forward* algorithm for the hash is not uselessly slow) and a hash, and produces a preimage. But it would not tell anything about the *degree* of that polynomial, or how large its constant factors are. So the polynomial algorithm might still not be *practically* feasible in the "128 bits" case.

Comment: I think answering the answer the OP "should (meant to?) have asked" instead of the one (s)he has, namely the relation between one-way functions and NP-completeness, would be more interesting (although this answer *does* address what the OP actually asked).